# Search and Add a text in a file name

Tags: batch-file, pdf, cmd

I need a batch file to search for a phrase "Ch_XX" and add a with it "Ch_XX_Pg" in PDF files.

The filename of my PDFs look like...

```
01_Vig12345_ch01_001-020.pdf
02_Vig12345_ch02_021-046.pdf
03_Vig12345_ch03_047-078.pdf
```

For these files, the output should be...

```
01_Vig12345_ch01_pg001-020.pdf
02_Vig12345_ch02_pg021-046.pdf
03_Vig12345_ch03_pg047-078.pdf
```

If a filename does not contain "CH", this "pg" should not added.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*_ch??_???-???.pdf) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!name!" "!name:~0,-11!pg!name:~-11!"
  endlocal
)
```

Delayed expansion is toggled on and off within the loop to protect any `!` that may be in the file name (unlikely, but possible).

The renamed file cannot match the file mask in the FOR loop, so there is no risk of renaming the file twice.

But if given a scenario where the new name could match the FOR file mask, then a single run could rename the file twice. In such a case the FOR loop would have to be changed to FOR /F processing the DIR /B command.